# Odyssey Outlook bar

Tags: wpf, outlook, themes

Odyssey outlook bar has three themes. How can I change theme for it in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution myself:

```
OutlookBar bar = new OutlookBar();
bar.Resources = Odyssey.Controls.Classes.SkinManager.WindowsSeven;
```

Answer (score 0):

The example code does the following:

```
SkinManager.SkinId = SkinId.OfficeBlack;
```